# JavaScript Regex Image search needs to require a CSS class name exist in the image tag

Tags: javascript, regex

The JavaScript function below is part of a MCEditor WYSIWYG Editor plugin for WordPress.

It searches the post text editor for images in this format:

```
<p><img src="http://test.dev/primary.jpg" class="mceItem code_syntax_highlighter" data-sh-attr="%20type%3D%22primary%22%20header%3D%22header-text%22%20footer%3D%22footer-text%22" data-sh-content="code-here" data-mce-resize="false" data-mce-placeholder="1" data-mce-src="http://test.dev/primary.jpg"></p>
```

It then replaces them with this:

```
[code_syntax_highlighter type="primary" header="header-text" footer="footer-text"]code-here[/code_syntax_highlighter]
```

The problem is that the RegEx below currently matches any image inside a `<p>` tag.

I need to modify it to only match images that have a matching CSS class name = `code_syntax_highlighter`

So if the image does not have a CSS class of `code_syntax_highlighter` then it will not be matched and replaced in the JavaScript below.

How can I modify the Regex to require the existence of this CSS class?

```
function restoreShortcodes2( content ) {
    return content.replace( /(?:<p(?: [^>]+)?>)*(<img [^>]+>)(?:<\/p>)*/g, function( match, image ) {
        var data1 = getAttr( image, 'data-sh-attr' );
        var con = getAttr( image, 'data-sh-code' );

        if ( data1 ) {
            return '<p>[' + short_code_tag + data1 + ']' + con + '[/'+short_code_tag+']</p>';
        }
        return match;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

replace your regex with this one

```
/(<img(\s*(?:\w+=".*")* class=".*code_syntax_highlighter.*" (?:\w+=".*")*)\/*>)/g
```

which should be

```
function restoreShortcodes2( content ) {
    return content.replace(/(<img(\s*(?:\w+=".*")* class=".*code_syntax_highlighter.*" (?:\w+=".*")*)\/*>)/g , function( match, image ) {
        var data1 = getAttr( image, 'data-sh-attr' );
        var con = getAttr( image, 'data-sh-code' );

        if ( data1 ) {
            return '<p>[' + short_code_tag + data1 + ']' + con + '[/'+short_code_tag+']</p>';
        }
        return match;
```

Comment: This works as long as I make sure my image tag has a space at the end before the closing `>` tag which is fine.  The other issue I have is that if my source text has more than 1 image that matches, it replaces all matches with 1 replacement now and before it would replace each match with a replacement.  Any ideas why that might not work now? thanks

Comment: ok let me try to correct the closing tag to make it robust. about the second issue am taking a deeper look at the code